# Input fields in one form required for one submit button, but not for other?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

How can I differentiate two separate actions for my submit buttons in one form, whereas one SAVES data into database (as is), and other submits form as a valid request, >>but<< according to **HTML5 native validation** (I use "required" attributes in HTML form)?

My form has 66 fields and I don't want to validate them all **in PHP AFTER submission** (as it's too cumbersome and time consuming), or validate them all in **JS BEFORE submission** (as I am not that agile in JS, as in PHP), so I use "required" and "type" attributes in HTML5, which is very convenient and quite versatile way of validation (besides older browsers).
However I cannot find a easy way to bypass the "required" attribute, when using save button, but not using "Send for submission" button. Can you help suggest a solution? I guess the prefered way is some JS/jQuery way, as I cannot determine which button would be used before hitting the button (so that I can make a field required or not).

Sample code:

```
<form>
A: <input type="text" name="A" required />
B: <input type="text" name="B" required />
C: <input type="text" name="C" />
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"> <!--do not require anything-->
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send  for submission"> <!-- require everything-->
</form>
```

Of course my form is huge, as it has 66 fields, so best solutions here are possibly general and versatile.

Comment: If you don't validate the data on the server end your just asking for trouble by being lazy. Client side validation is purely for enhanced ux, and should never be relied on.

Comment: I agree with you totally. I just have my back on the wall with time gone and need a compromise here ... This is not for the best possible approach, but barely viable, with update/upgrade asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've eventually come up with something like this.
HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onClick="removeRequired(this.form)">
```

JS (using jQuery):

```
function removeRequired(form){
    $.each(form, function(key, value) {
        if ( value.hasAttribute("required")){
            value.removeAttribute("required");
        }
    });
}
```

This is tested and working. It has this nice property, that I can keep the function elsewhere in files, to not clutch the php/html that is executing it.
Only improvement I'd like (and probably other would be interested in) would be to eliminate jQuery as it's only used for browsing each input element in form, which seems easy enough for pure JS. However I could not find an easy way, and run out of time and used above with jQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might get you started:

```js
$('#sub1').click(function() {
  $('[name=A]').removeAttr('required');
  $('[name=B]').removeAttr('required');
  $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="save" />');
  $('form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  A: <input type="text" name="A" required /><br>
  B: <input type="text" name="B" required /><br>
  C: <input type="text" name="C" /><br>
  <input id="sub1" type="button" name="save" value="Save">
  <!--do not require anything-->
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send  for submission">
  <!-- require everything-->
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Just add the `<script>` tag that I just now added into the answer. You can either put it in your `<head>`, or just before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: However, as I said I have 66 fields, which around 40 has the required attribute. I'd like to run a function outside the document, that would do the job, to not clutch the document. How can I pass the whole form to a function that would do that? Aa I said, I'm not that into JS...

Comment: @JanDesta - I posted another answer that might answer this point. If not, please respond back.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the required attribute from all tags before submitting, modify the code to:

```
$('#sub1').click(function() {
  $('[required]').removeAttr('required');
  $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="save" />').submit();
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vthqrdqz/)</kbd> *to show it works*

Note this answer also demonstrates chaining the jQuery methods: `$(tag).append().submit()`